# 'Could no access URL through the external browser.' in deployment of RESTful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, netbeans

i am using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 and building REST Web services in java. i am using Apache Tomcat server 7.0.52 and Windows 7 os, when i click on test RESTful web service in NetBeans. first it shows a dialog in NetBeans with message "Could no access URL through the external browser. Check the browser configuration." and the it opens default browser(Mozilla firefox in my case) with error status 404 The requested resource is not available.

i have tested it with old as well as new Mozilla firefox browser. in my case Apache tomcat server is starting and when i close the NetBeans the it also stops Apache tomcat server properly. thanks.

Comment: The URL should be composed like this: `http://{tomcat_url}:{tomcat_port}/{application_root}/{service_class_@path}/{service_class_method_@path}`. If you figure out all these variables, your response will be 200 OK. Where `{tomcat_url}` is most propably `localhost`, defualt `{tomcat_port}` is 8080, `{application_root}` is in your project configuration and following vars depends on your code annotations. So try to figure out your URL by yourself and compare it with the one Netbeans is trying to access. This problem is not browser dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat installed by Netbeans is configured with ports different from http 80 and https 443 standard ports, so check first the port configured in your Netbeans Tomcat server, then specify that port in the your URL.